# Do aircraft use some kind of stability control to keep the aircraft on the runway during landing?

Tags: landing, flight-controls, pilots, autopilot

Modern automobiles use an electronic system called ESP to keep the car on track in slippery situations. Do modern jet liners have a similar system to aid the pilot in keeping the aircraft on the runway after touchdown?

Especially during crosswind landings you can feel the plane swilling violently left/right after touchdown.

Comment: Autopilot landing is helpful as the rudder will be controlled by the autopilot to keep the aircraft on the runway.